# Opengl rendering dynamic textured quad

Tags: opengl

I want to draw textured quad, but texture is changing every frame. My texture is `128x128` rgb array. I store each pixel's rgb value in that array and i am changing that array every frame. Also my window size is `1024x1024`. I want my pixel array fullscreen, so i am creating a texture and add this texture in to a full-size quad. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GLuint texID;

void initphase()
{
    /* create texture object */
    glGenTextures(1, &texID)
    /* bind texture and allocate storage */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        …,
        NULL /* just initialize */
    );
    /* alternative:
     * Use glTexStorage instead of glTexImage.
     * Requires a few changed in how texture is used though */

    /* set parameters like filtering mode, and such */
    glTexParameteri(…);
}

void player()
{
    while(playing){
        glClear(…);
        glViewport(…);

        /* draw other stuff */

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
        /* copy image to texture */
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, …, image_data);
        if( using_shaders ){
             glUseProgram(…);
             setup_modelview_and_projection_uniforms();
        } else {
             glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
             setup_modelview_and_projection_matrices();
        }
        glDraw…(…); /* draw quad */

        /* draw other stuff */
        swap_buffers();
    }
}
```